# Proving that a relation is well-defined

Tags: proof-verification, logic

[image]

I know that in general to show a map $f:X\to Y$ is well-defined, we need to show that for any $x\in X$, $f(x)=y_1$ and $f(x)=y_2$ imply that $y_1=y_2$, i.e. each element of $X$ is related to exactly one element of $Y$.

I am reading the proof of theorem 4 on page 56 of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition. On the second and third lines of the proof, he says we need to show $x^r=x^s$ implies $\varphi(x^r)=\varphi(x^s)$ in order to prove $\varphi$ is well-defined.

How is this logically equivalent to the statement that each element of the domain is related to exactly one element of the range?

I see his argument shows that the map $\varphi$ is independent of the specific choice of representative in $\langle x\rangle$. Is that equivalent to the map being well-defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I know that in general to show a map f:X→Y is well-defined, we need to show that for any x∈X, f(x)=y1 and f(x)=y2 imply that y1=y2,

That's sort of true.  But as a definition for being "well-defined" it isn't .... well, defined.

Let's take a specific example of something that is not well defined:

For and $n = a\cdot b; n, a,b \in \mathbb N$ define $f(ab) = a$.  That's obviously not well-defined because if we view $20$ as $1*20$ or $4*5$ or $10*2$ we'll get that maybe $f(1*20) = 1$ but $f(4*5) = 4$ and $f(10*2) = 10$ etc.

That just doesnt make any sense.

And that *sort of* fits your definition.

$f(20) =1$ and $f(20) = 4$ but $1\ne 4$ so not well-defined... except... how can we *say* $f(20) = 4$, how did we decide that that time it'd pop out a $4$ but the next time $f(20) = 1$ it popped out a $1$?  Do we just sit and wait for all of them?

Thing is $f$ is defined on *representations* and not actually on the numbers.  SO to show something is well defined we must show if $a*b = n$ and $c*d = n$ are two representations of the some number then we must show that it will always be such that $f(a*b) = a$ and $f(c*d) = c$ that $a = c$.

And, of course, that is bollucks and that is whay it is not well defined.

On the other hand if something is defined on the *number* then... it's determined for that number.  Period.  If $f(n) =K$ then .... $f(n)$ will always be $K$ and it can't be anything else.  So if something is defined specifically on the *number* and not the representation, then the issue of being well defined is not a concern.

(The nuance, of course, is recognizing when a definition is innate to the number or to the representation.)

But sometimes a representation definition *is* okay.

Two examples (one familiar and one probably taken for granted without question): i)  Define $\sqrt{x}$ as the number (if any) so that $y \ge 0;$ and $y^2 = x$.  This is well defined *IF* we can show that for any $y^2 = x$ and $y_1^2 = x$ and $y\ge 0$ and $y_1 \ge 0$ then $y= y_1$.  And we can prove that.  (If $y_1 \ne y$ then one is smaller than the other; wolog we'll assume $0 \le y_1 < y$.  So then $y_1^2 < y^2$.  So they aren't equal). So it is well defined.

ii) for $b > 0$ define $b^q$ for $q \in \mathbb Q; q = \frac nm; n,m \in \mathbb Z$ as $(\sqrt[m]{b})^n$.  Well if $q = \frac nm = \frac rs$ how do we know $(\sqrt[m]{b})^n= (\sqrt[s]{b})^r$?  For example $q =\frac 12 = \frac 36$ how do we know that $\sqrt b = (\sqrt[6]{b})^3$

> I see his argument shows that the map φ is independent of the specific choice of representative in ⟨x⟩. Is that equivalent to the map being well-defined?

In a word, yes.

He wants to say $x\mapsto y; x^2 \mapsto y^2; .... ;x^{n-1}\mapsto y^{n-1}; e\mapsto e$. and if he had said that there'd be no question of being well-defined if we assume that all the $x^k; 0\le k < n$ are distinct.

But if we can't assume they are distinct and we have a more general: $x^k \mapsto y^k$...  Well there is the possiblity that $x^k = x^{k+r}$ but $y^k \ne y^{k+r}$.  We have to prove that is not an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your very thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 3):

You say that to show a map $f :X \to Y$ is well defined we need to show that if $f(x) = y_1$ and $f(x)=y_2$ then $y_1 = y_2$. That is true.

An equivalent formulation is that if $x=y$ then we must have $f(x) = f(y)$.

This is what the proof does. Since $x^k = x^{n+k} = x^{2n+k} = \cdots$ we need to check that it doesn't matter whether we define $f(x^k)$ to be  $y^k$ or $y^{n+k}$ or ...

Answer (score 0):

In a cyclic group Every element w is a power of x but there will be many choices of the power say r and s .So $w=x^r=x^s$ ,one must show $x^{r+k}=x^{s+k}$.